# Taking advantage of JSON in list manipulation with R for aggregation

Tags: r, list, apply, gini

I have a JSON file such as :

```
{
  "openmole-version" : "16.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "execution-id" : "5b6cf33c-f219-4107-a81a-d8911b68d5df",
  "script" : {
    "content" : "import _file_.jeu_niayes_inputs._\n\nval env = LocalEnvironment(1) \n\nDirectSampling(\n  evaluation = javaTask,\n  sampling = \n    (i in (0 to 1 by 1))\n) hook (workDirectory / \"result_one\", Seq(i, result, waterConsumption, capitalAccumulation), \n        format = OMROutputFormat()) on env\n",
    "import" : [ {
      "import" : "_file_.jeu_niayes_inputs",
      "content" : "val i = Val[Int]\nval cap1 = Val[Double]\nval cap2 = Val[Double]\nval cap3 = Val[Double]\nval cap4 = Val[Double]\nval surf1 = Val[Int]\nval surf2 = Val[Int]\nval surf3 = Val[Int]\nval surf4 = Val[Int]\n\nval result = Val[Array[Array[Double]]]\nval capitalAccumulation = Val[Double]\nval waterConsumption = Val[Double]\n\n//Defines the task to perform the hello function\nval javaTask = ScalaTask(\"\"\"\n  import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters.*\n  val o = \n    fr.ocelet.model.jeu_niayes.Jeu_Niayes.run(cap1, cap2, cap3, cap4, surf1, surf2, surf3, surf4)\n  val result = o.asScala.values.map(_.asScala.map(_.doubleValue).toArray).toArray\n  val waterConsumption = result.map(a => a(1)).sum\n  val capitalAccumulation = result.map(a => a(2)).sum\n  \"\"\") set (\n  libraries += workDirectory / \"jeu_niayes_input.jar\",\n  inputs += i,\n  inputs += (cap1, cap2, cap3, cap4, surf1, surf2, surf3, surf4),\n  outputs += (i, cap1, cap2, cap3, cap4, surf1, surf2, surf3, surf4, result, waterConsumption, capitalAccumulation),\n  // Default values. Can be removed if OpenMOLE Vals are set by values coming from the workflow\n  cap1 := 10,\n  cap2 := 11,\n  cap3 := 12,\n  cap4 := 13,\n  surf1 := 3,\n  surf2 := 3,\n  surf3 := 3,\n  surf4 := 3\n) \n\n"
    } ]
  },
  "time-start" : 1698137764864,
  "time-save" : 1698137766281,
  "data" : [ {
    "variables" : {
      "i" : [ 0, 1 ],
      "result" : [ [ [ 4.1339999999999995, 63.5, 127.0, 0.0, 1.0, 10.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0 ], [ 4.1339999999999995, 0.5, 5.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 3.0 ], [ 4.1339999999999995, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0 ], [ 4.1339999999999995, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ] ], [ [ 5.655, 29.0, 140.0, 0.0, 1.0, 10.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 0.0, 5.0, 4.0 ], [ 5.655, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0 ], [ 5.655, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0 ], [ 5.655, 26.0, 31.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 0.0, 1.0 ] ] ],
      "waterConsumption" : [ 72.0, 59.0 ],
      "capitalAccumulation" : [ 132.0, 171.0 ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

From `result` I'd like to calcul for each index :

- Sum for 2nd number
- gini from 2nd number

[image: firefox screenshot of my JSON file]

I use :

```r
library(jsonlite)
# Lire le fichier JSON
data <- fromJSON("~/Téléchargements/result.json")
results <- data$data$variables$result
dim(results)
#[1]  2  4 13
a <- as.data.frame(results[[1]][,,2]) #take number 1 from JSON snapshot
```

I don't know how to calculate sum and gini by index